# To push tuple values to a excel sheet wise using python

Tags: python-2.7

I have written a python script to parse through multiple html files using beautifulsoup . My goal is to push the data to excel files iteratively sheet wise . I am able to create worksheets in excel bu executing the program and also able to fill the first row in each of the wrok sheets . I am stuck at how the all the data ( for example 99 rows ) can be moved to excel row wise . I am using openpyxl . Could anyone tell me how can i achieve this .

```
for tr in trs:
    cells = tr.findAll('td')
    if len(cells) == 5 :
        rsm = cells[0].string
        hostname = cells[1].string`enter code here`
        errormessage = cells[3].string
            #print errormessage`enter code here`
        applicationname = cells[4].string
        ff.append((rsm, hostname, errormessage, applicationname))

        #print row
leng += len(ff)
#print ff
#print leng
filename = "find_acs_errors_"+name[3]+".csv"
print filename
with open(filename, 'wb') as result:
    writer = csv.writer(result, dialect='excel')
    writer.writerow(['RSM','HOSTNAME','ERRORMESSAGE','APPLICATIONNAME'])
    for row in ff:
        writer.writerow(row)

    #mywriter.writerow(row)

result.close()
```

I tried with CSV , the above code is the same . I am able export all the rows as expected in a csv file . But not able to add one more worksheet in the same csv file created . I came to know that we wouldnt be able to multiple worksheets in a csv file which is already created . So i tried using openpyxl , i unfortunately did not save the code , i will be sharing it soon . Could you please let me know if we can achieve the same using csv module ?

Comment: Try sharing what you have tried?

Comment: Hello Brian, I have edited my question with updated script ..